# Hide list column on new, edit item-OOTB

Tags: list, list-view, custom-list, ootb

I have a SharePoint list. There I have created a new column "Department".
I want to keep it hidden when adding new item and edit item. It should be visible in list view. No code base (OOTB).

Comment: I did that, but it is not working. Is it because I am using InfoPath? I tried saving the form in InfoPath with the changes imported from the site, and republishing, but it basically undoes the "hide". Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. It's applicable for SharePoint OOTB form only.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- To begin, go to List Settings > Advanced Settings
- Select Yes on Allow management of content types
- Click on one of the existing content types under the Content Type
  section Next, click on the column you intend to hide, and choose the
  option Hidden.  Click OK
- Go to the New Item tab and select the Edit form.  You will see that,
  on both the New Item and Edit forms, the field that you want to hide
  is not shown, and you're able to save the item without filling in a
  value for it.

Comment: **Content Types** section is normally hidden and it will be visible after "Select Yes on Allow management of content types" step.

Comment: @FurkanEkinci You can reset the option to no when you are finished making your changes and that should re-hide it.