# Hide fields in new item menu

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, list-form, spfield

I have followed the answer described in [Hide list column on new, edit item-OOTB](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/hide-list-column-on-new-edit-item-ootb)

But what I found is when editing the column from the content type, i found the hidden menu is disabled.

**Content type description :**

[image: Content types]

**Approved field settings :**

[image: approved field settings]

Why does this problem occur?

Comment: Try it from SharePoint Designer. Also check you have enough permission.

Comment: trying it from the system account.

Comment: ohhh!! then try to hide it from designer. **Open site in designer** --> **Click On List/Library** -->  **Click on your list** --> **Click on content type** --> **Click on edit content type** --> **double click on your column**

Comment: **surprisingly** double click does not work sometime. in that case, you may need multiple click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens for **Yes/No (check box)** column but it is possible to hide it from SharePoint Designer. Follow below steps to hide from Designer.

1. Open site in designer
2. Click On List/Library from left side
3. Click on your list
4. Click on edit content type
5. Click multiple times (may be it is six times) on your column and then you will get your column in edit mode. Now select the option from drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution**

If you want hide any field  from NEW/VIEW/EDIT item Forms. Then you can simply  achieve this using SPUtility.js, Its very simple and useful. You can download js file from [sputility](https://sputility.codeplex.com/releases/view/620734)

Steps:

1. Edit NEW/VIEW/EDIT item form in SharePoint UI.
2. Add Script editor web part.

Add the following script in Script editor web part.

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
SPUtility.HideSPField('FieldNameToHide');  
});
</script>
```

Ok & Save the page.
Now specified field will not be visible.

If you want to Show that field again then you can use,

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
SPUtility.ShowSPField('FieldNameToShow');
});
</script>
```

SPUtility.js is a JavaScript library used to make modifications to SharePoint's list forms (NewForm.aspx, DispForm and EditForm.aspx in a survey, custom list or library). It works with SharePoint 2007, 2010, and 2013 (including SharePoint Online / Office 365).

[SPUtility.js Documentation](https://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Common%20SPField%20functions)

Comment: Is that a good practice to choose coding solution what I can do using default feature? Why should I add an extra library to show/hide a field?

Comment: @ Atish. Using OOTB way is always a good practice. No doubt. But i already mentioned that this is an alternative solution in case if you cant able to hide it in OOTB way. Also SPUtility is a rich js library that allows us to hide fields based on conditions &  Its offers lots of list forms customization.

Comment: No complain on **SPUtility**. We should find the actual problem before proposing an alternative, shouldn't we?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little SharePoint PnP function to update a field Hidden setting

```
function setFieldHidden([string]$inListName,[string]$inContentTypeName,[string]$infieldTitle,[int]$hide1vis0){

$Connection = Get-PnPConnection #assumes you are connected to PnP site.

# Get list content type object
$ListContentType = Get-PnPContentType -list $inListName -Identity $inContentTypeName
$lcFields = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $ListContentType -Connection $Connection -Property "Fields" 
foreach($field in $lcFields){

    if($field.Title -eq $infieldTitle){

        $ListContentTypeField = $field
     }
}



$ListContentTypeField

# Code to set content type field hidden
$ListContentType.FieldLinks.GetById($ListContentTypeField.Id).Hidden = $hide1vis0

# Update(UpdateChildren – bool), this value indicates whether the children content type(inheriting from this Content Type) needs to be updated. 0 = False, 1 = True
$ListContentType.Update(0)

$Connection.Context.ExecuteQuery()


}
```