# How to show the approver's name and approval date

Tags: workflow, list-view, column, approval

I have one custom list on a Sharepoint 2013 site. I'm using the OOTB default approval Workflow from Sharepoint 2010. Everytime a new record is created in this custom list the workflow is started and routed for approval to a group of people so that any of them can Accept or Reject the request.

On my list view I can add the workflow status column from the "modify this view" menu to display the status, but I would like to also display the user who approved it or rejected it and the date it was approved. Is it possible to do it? If i check the workflow history I notice that information is already in there (user and date of approval) but I would like it printed as an additional column in my list view.

Your support is really appreciated.

[image: Approval workflow]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an extra column for that and show it in the View/New View.
Now once item is approved/Rejected by the **user from the Approvers group**, just Add the Display Name of the Approved/Rejected person in the new Custom column.(You can do the same for the date also).
Hope this would help you!

Comment: If you add a Column called, for example, `Approved By`, how do you hide this field from showing on the `New Item` form (so that the original submitter cannot add and adjust the value in this field)? Edit: Actually, maybe the answer to my query is here:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/141861

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a custom workflow. I stopped using the default approval workflow and created a new one and used the instruction start approval workflow as the only step.

If you click on "Approval" you can edit the behaviors of the workflow. in my case I edited the behavior of a single task:

[image]

Inside of it I assigned the values to the corresponding columns:

[image]

By using the default approval workflow I wasn't able to do the last step since the columns weren't available. I guess because it was the global workflow. And since I created a list workflow the columns were now available.