# SharePoint Online: (Microsoft 365) Add Approved By / Rejected By Column in Documents Section

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

[image: Default Approval Flow Template]

Hi. This has been bugging me for 3 hours now. I am not sure why the default approval Flow does not track who approved the document for crying out loud. Sorry for venting out my frustration for something like this to be such a pain to implement is a mystery to me.

So I added an "Approved By / Rejected By Column" in my Sharepoint Documents section. This is to keep track of document approvals obviously and to establish a more streamlined approach in document currency.

The default Flow template is listed below. I CANNOT find any action that will let me extract who the approval was sent to and store it somewhere and show it under the Approve / Rejected by column.

Any thoughts on this? i found a link that is sort of similar to what i am trying to do but this is the old sharepoint infrastructure: [How to show the approver's name and approval date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195173/how-to-show-the-approvers-name-and-approval-date)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reference you mentioned only applies to workflows, which has a separated workflow task list to store the approval tasks.

Microsoft Flow does not have such list to retrieve data from. The data you need can be found via `Power Automate > Action items > Approvals > History > click task > Activity`.

[image]

All approvals in this tenant are managed this way. I don’t think this field is something we can grab information from, at least not with OOB solutions.

---

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Hi Chelsea, thank you for the response. Unfortunately this is sharepoint online. I am not able to find those power automate sub menus.

Comment: @wh3resmycar2 The instruction I provided is from Microsoft 365. I’ve added a screenshot of the side menu in https://flow.microsoft.com/. Please see the updated answer.