# Match two list items (different lists). If they match copy another column

Tags: list, workflow, cascading, copy-item

Currently I am trying to create a workflow where once someone inputs a name into a people picker field, the workflow then matches that submitted name to another list.  Once match has been made I need to the workflow to copy the team that the employee is on to the first list.

List 1 is an out list, where the workflow will reside.  This is where I need the team name from list 2 to be copied to.

List 2 is a directory list, where the employee name will be matched and where the team name is stored.

Is this possible?  Or if there is another way to look up this information and auto populate a field, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Let us create dummy lists List 1 and List 2 (following you) :

***List 1***:

Id (column 1)

Employee(column 2 and data type Person  Group)

Team (column 3 and data type Person  Group)

List 1:

[image]

**Note** : You need to keep column **Team** hidden from forms, so that user is unable to enter this value, as this value will be updated using the workflow.
To do this follow [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/hide-list-column-on-new-edit-item-ootb)

***List 2*** :

Id (column 1)

Employee (column 2 and data type Person  Group)

Team (column 3 and data type Person  Group)

List 2:

[image]

The workflow(2010 type) which will run on List1 is as follows:

the first action will be 'set variable to' and lookup will be like:

[image]

the second action will be 'Update item in this list' and lookup will be like:

[image]

**Note** : The workflow will run on 'Start workflow automatically when an item is created'.

If you have more queries let me know. If you find the answer helful please do mark it.

Comment: The workflow is completing but not updating the list item.  Does there need to be a "copy" action?

Comment: Please add a log message action in the workflow just after the 1st action. Then after publishing it, test it again. You must have notice a new column with the same name as workflow has been created. Please click on it and see if the log appears there (which you added in workflow). This assures us if the correct team name is retrieved that means the problem is with the second step.