# SharePoint Issue Tracker - How To Edit The New Form/Screen

Tags: issue-tracking

In an effort to convince management to use SharePoint for tracking Customer Service issues, I've created a project using the Issue Tracker.

So far, everything seems to be going well and I may sell them on this.

One thing I did notice is that the NEW Entry Form/Screen doesn't seem to match up with the data I need.

[image]

[image]

If I go to QUICK EDIT, it shows only the columns I want but this NEW form shows data fields I do not need.

Just trying to locate the screen where I can edit this.

Thanks...

Comment: I found this link and this did the exact trick for me. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/hide-list-column-on-new-edit-item-ootb

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of SharePoint Online but in case of on premise SharePoint you can add/delete columns by switching over "List Settings" and if you need to hide an existing field(which you do not want to delete) then JSOM code will work for you.

[image]

See the green Box. If you are unable to get that then you do not have an admin rights to create new field.

Comment: Thank you. I've gone to LIST SETTINGS but I can't seem to find this NEW ITEM screen/form to edit.