# SharePoint column fill notification in SharePoint designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, column

I am using SharePoint designer 2013 and want to notify certain people if a specific column in the list has been updated by someone. I simply want to know what can I use in the stages so that it can start working?

Choice menu: CAB Advisory to Release Manager.
Options are : successful, ON-hold, rejected.

So if the CAB advisory member selects any of these from this options then the people are needed to be informed that a decision has been made and they can check it out.

Thank you very much in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. Create a SharePoint Designer workflow.
2. Add **IF condition** in your workflow.
3. Check if your column (CAB Advisory to Release Manager) **is empty** or **is not empty**.
4. If the field is not empty that means the decision has been made and then you can send an Email to your targeted users.

**Example**: Considering my column name is "Approval Status".

[image]

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
Thanks for your response.
As I am a beginner in SharePoint designer. In the if condition I cannot see the option of if the value is empty or not. Is there any formula for this that we have to use?
 If yes and you can tell me this will be great.
Cheers.

Comment: Are using SP designer 2013 workflow and the data type of your column is "Choice"?? Check above screenshot.

Comment: Yes Ganesh that's right. I am trying this now and will let you know shortly. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent! This worked... Thank you!!!

Comment: I have another question if you can help me with this. I have done this and it's working but whenever if someone edited the form and modified it after the CAB advisory to Release manager column is not empty it will again send the email to people. I hope you get what I mean. Is there anyway to stopping it or something similar I can do? Cheers

Comment: You can create one hidden field in your list (maybe of type choice with options Yes & No and default value set to "No) . Say your column name is "IsEmailSentOnce". set its value to Yes when you first time send the email.

Comment: In this case you need to add one more IF condition to your workflow inside existing IF condition. And it will check "If Current Item:IsEmailSentOnce is equal to No". So the send email action will be executed only once.

Comment: I will do, thank you Ganesh. You are great. I have posted another question on my profile. Can you please answer me that as well. It will be very helpful.
Cheers.

Comment: I am not able to hide the column for some reason, I have created a column in the list and it is showing up in the form and that's something I don't want to be in the form. Can you help me with this? Cheers

Comment: You can make your field hidden from content type settings. Check the answer given at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/hide-list-column-on-new-edit-item-ootb

Comment: This worked. Thanks man!!!