# Hide document set columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, form, document-set, sharepoint-administration

I have a column (Process) in the document set that should remain displayed on the overview page (screenshot) where all the documents can be found. When I edit the properties (2. screenshot), however, it should no longer be there. How is that possible?

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: Try below solution and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

From a document library: (If you have properties form open like screenshot 2, skip step 1 & 2)

1. Select a file.
2. In the **Information Pane**:

   - Locate the **Properties** section.
   - Click **Edit all**.
3. At the top of the form, select **Edit Form** > **Edit columns**.
4. In the **Edit columns** pane, check (to show) or uncheck (to hide) the box for the column or columns as needed.
5. When you're finished, select **Save**.

**Reference**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

Comment: When i do this, then i will dont see the column in the document set too (screen 1). It should be stay there, only when i edit properties it should be hide or only readable.

Comment: If you hide the column for library forms, it should not remove it from library view.

Comment: I carried out your instructions.
Unfortunately I don't see an "Edit Form" for your 3rd point (see screenshot) 
Screenshot: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-e82824-1614265682.jpg.html

Comment: Then you can try the old (classic) way to hide the column from forms: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/hide-list-column-on-new-edit-item-ootb